# Standard Lightning Spinner turns constantly after a screen flow action execution on Work Order Object

Tags: work-order

I have a flow action on the work order object under the activity tab because its a classic behaviour in salesforce for Work Order and Case Object.

When I launch the screen flow, the execution is good and the actions on server side are well executed.But after clicking the finish button a spinner appear in the page and turns constantly, as if the flow had not ended. The only way to stop the spinner rotation is refresh the page.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: add your code please.

Comment: you are setting spinner attribute to false on callback?   like this...component.set("v.Spinner", false);

Comment: @nube Hi, it's not a lightning component this screen flow is a salesforce standard process I don't have access to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my standard process screen flow : 
[image]